# powershell replace line in file only when line does NOT start with a certain character

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this line of powershell regex to replace a line in a configuration file. The idea is to replace any line containing the word "Listen", followed immediately by any number.

```
(gc  .\path\httpd.conf) -replace  "Listen \d+", "Listen 999"
```

As you can guess, it's trying to programmatically change a Port declaration in a configuration file, replacing any existing number with "999".

Problem is, the replacement happens but also affects lines like these:

```
#Listen 111
 #Listen 222
# Listen 333
```

These commented lines should not be matched/replaced.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `(gc  .\path\httpd.conf) -replace  '(?<!^\s*#.*?)\bListen \d+', 'Listen 999'` or `(gc  .\path\httpd.conf) -replace  '^([^#]*)\bListen \d+', '$1Listen 999'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```
^[^#]*Listen \d+
```

### Demo

This would match any line which did not contain a comment `#` character at any from from the start of line before the occurrence of `Listen \d+`.  Your updated code:

```
(gc  .\path\httpd.conf) -replace  "^[^#]*Listen \d+", "Listen 999"
```

Comment: So, the idea is to use the `^` character to mark beginning of line, and again as the negation sign within the square braces . Thank you, @Tim. This works quite okay.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo: Tim's helpful answer indeed works well, but as a general pointer (even though it may not be necessary here): you may want to add `\b` to the regex so that `Listen` only matches on a _word boundary_: `'^[^#]*\bListen \d+'` - that way, something like `Listen 42` would match, but `NotListen 42` would not.

Comment: Many thanks @mklement0 for the optimization advice.